# Infinite scroll does not work and no error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make an Infinite Scroll plugin work and it simply don't. I've tried several plugins and it simply doesn't affect at all the page. It's not like it says an error message; instead nothing happens.

Here is the Infinite Scroll configuration page:

[image: This is the Infinite Scroll Plugin configuration page.]

I just have to describe my site's right selectors and set it on the plugin. Then it should automatically start infinite scrolling my index page posts.

This is my website code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 posts-bottom">
 <?php query_posts('category_name=home&showposts=15'.$num_posts.'&paged='.get_query_var('paged').'&p='.$ids);       
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++;?>
    <div class="post-unit">
        <div class="foto">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"> <img id="imagem-post" class="thumbnail-post" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p class="date-post"> • <?php echo get_the_date( 'd/m/Y \à\s H:i' ); ?> </p>
            <a class="link-title-post" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <h2> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2> </a>
            <?php $subtitulo = get_post_custom_values('subtitulo'); ?>
            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <p class="subtitle"> <?php echo $subtitulo[0] ?> </p> </a>
            <?php $titulo_whats = rawurlencode('Vi essa notícia e lembrei de você: ');
            $link_whats = rawurlencode(get_the_permalink()); ?>
            <div id="share-buttons-small">
                <a class="face-icon" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="google-icon" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="twitter-icon" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;hashtags=goiasverdade" target="_blank"></a>
                <a class="whats-icon" href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $titulo_whats;?> <?php echo $link_whats;?>" target="_blank"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div> 
    <div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>
</div>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

If you'd like to check my website's code, here's the link: http://goiasverdade.com.br

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd take a step back and calm down first. 3 hours of failure isn't that bad. I've spent almost a week debugging a single issue before.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: This one: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/ I've also tried others but I got the same result

Comment: Honestly, I 'don't understand why people are voting down my topic

Comment: What version of word press are you using? Because it says on the page `This plugin hasn’t been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.`

Comment: I'm using the newest version. I've seen this, but I'm trying this plugin after I've tried all the new and updated ones already

Comment: So I'd like to know if you guys recognize an error on my code

Comment: I also find it very weird that it doesn't show anything on the console also, like if nothing new had been activated on my site.

Comment: Well I think navigation doesn't have any direct anchor child element

Comment: @Ayan, when the page is loaded a link appears inside the

Comment: Definitely it does but the link I suppose are inside `<p> tags` so maybe you could try something like `.navigation p a` as your next selector.

Answer (score 0):

I visited your site and being a blog type or list based I would suggest you try this code.

Your jQuery should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var win = $(window);

    // Each time the user scrolls
    win.scroll(function() {
        // End of the document reached?
        if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
            $('#loading').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'get-post.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#posts').append(html);
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and your html should be

```
<ul id="posts">
<li>
    <article>content</article>
</li>

</ul>

<p id="loading">
    <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading…" />
</p>
```

Comment: OP wants it with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it and leave the feedback later

Comment: Tried it and still doesn't work... I give up, thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Dont give up try this plugin this is what i always use

Comment: @dagmawi, I've installed Jquery, the plugin and called the function in the theme header. It didn't work, and when I go to the console log of JavaScript, it says ("...").jscroll is not a function. That's really weird, cause when I enter the script files of the plugin it works properly. Any clue on what could be causing this?